# Error? Can’t Figure Out

Tags: python, error-handling, tkinter

I am creating a tkinter program and ran into this weird error. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *   
def get_info(key):     
    pass   
def create_new():  
    create = Toplevel(root)
    create.title('Create A New Contact')
    Label(create, text='Name: ').grid(row=0, sticky=W+E)
    name = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=1, sticky=W+E)
    Label(create, text='Address(ex. 1111 Main St, MyCity, Anystate 12345): ', wrapLength=1).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
    address = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=3, sticky=W+E)
def access():
    access_window = Toplevel(root)
    access_window.title("Access a Contact")
    Label(access_window, text=“Enter a first name: ‘).grid(row=0, sticky=‘W+E’)#Error here
    access_key = Entry(access_window, width=8).grid(row=0, sticky='W+E')
    Button(access_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: get_info(access_key.get('0.0', 'end-1c'))).grid(row=2, sticky='W+E')
root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
button1 = Button(root, text="Create New", command=create_new).grid(row=0, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text=“Access Person”, command=access).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

The console says:

```
Error: EOL while scanning string literal.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same kind of quotation marks to mark the start and end of a string.

So the line you highlighted needs use consistent quotation marks - you shouldn't mix single and double quotes. Your line need to look like this

```
Label(access_window, text="Enter a first name: ").grid(row=0, sticky=‘W+E’)
```

Or this

```
Label(access_window, text='Enter a first name: ').grid(row=0, sticky=‘W+E’)
```

Not this, where you start with a double quote and end with a single quote

```
Label(access_window, text=“Enter a first name: ‘).grid(row=0, sticky=‘W+E’)
```

Answer (score 3):

This line has invalid characters:

```
Label(access_window, text=“Enter a first name: ‘).grid(row=0, sticky=‘W+E’)
#                       --^                  --^                   --^ --^
```

So does this one:

```
button2 = Button(root, text=“Access Person”, command=access).grid(row=0, column=1)
#                         --^           --^
```

In Python, string literals may only be enclosed by normal apostrophes `'` or normal quotation marks `"`.

---

To fix the problem, replace each `“` and `‘` with a `"`:

```
Label(access_window, text="Enter a first name: ").grid(row=0, sticky="W+E")

button2 = Button(root, text="Access Person", command=access).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

---

Also, the `grid` method of every Tkinter widget works in-place (it always returns `None`).  Thus, you should call it on its own line:

```
button2 = Button(root, text="Access Person", command=access)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: I don't disagree with this - but note in his question the problem was with the Label(access_window...) line as denoted by his comment

Comment: @dannymilsom - Oh, I didn't see he was doing it there too.  Let me edit my answer.