# Another error with my code

Tags: python, error-handling, tkinter

Another error with my code! Man, I just keep getting them…  My previous one(fixed) 
is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772838/error-cant-figure-out)

```
from Tkinter import *   
def get_info(key):
    pass#do more later
def create_new():
    create = Toplevel(root)
    create.title('Create A New Contact')
    Label(create, text='Name: ').grid(row=0, sticky=W+E)
    name = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=1, sticky=W+E)
    Label(create, text='Address(ex. 1111 Main St, MyCity, Anystate 12345): ', wrapLength=1).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
    address = Entry(create, width=8).grid(row=3, sticky=W+E)
def access():
    access_window = Toplevel(root)
    access_window.title("Access a Contact")
    Label(access_window, text="Enter a first name: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W+E)
    access_key = Entry(access_window, width=8).grid(row=1, sticky=W+E)
    Button(access_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: get_info(access_key.get('0.0', 'end-1c'))).grid(row=2, sticky='W+E')
root = Tk()
root.title('Address Book')
button1 = Button(root, text="Create New", command=create_new).grid(row=0, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text=“Access Person”, command=access).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

There should be nothing wrong with this, but there is. It is not an error, just when I click the “Create New” button only the name entry shows up, everything else doesn’t. With the “Access Person” button, it only shows “Enter a name: “ and no entry.

Comment: Is this python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Good practice in Tkinter is to wrap the code up in classes. Also you should keep references to your widgets and the line `button1 = Button(root, text="Create New", command=create_new).grid(row=0, column=0)` is only going to set `button1=None`. To get the reference, first create the button, then grid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in your code:

First, wrap length needs to have a lowercase 'L':

```
Label(create, text='Address(ex. 1111 Main St, MyCity, Anystate 12345): ', wrapLength=1).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
                                                                              ^
```

Changed to

```
Label(create, text='Address(ex. 1111 Main St, MyCity, Anystate 12345): ', wraplength=1).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
                                                                              ^
```

Second, you accidentally added quotes around one of the `W+E`s. Change this line:

```
Button(access_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: get_info(access_key.get('0.0', 'end-1c'))).grid(row=2, sticky='W+E')
                                                                                                                   ^   ^
```

To this

```
Button(access_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: get_info(access_key.get('0.0', 'end-1c'))).grid(row=2, sticky=W+E)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's your problem:
TclError: bad stickyness value "W+E": must be a string containing n, e, s, and/or w

TclError: unknown option "-wrapLength"

fix those and it'll finish assembling the gui

Comment: So you are incorrect about the first line. If the OP has done a `from Tkinter import *`, then `W+E="we"`.